# Using condition for redirecting in react router dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently getting troubled with the react router dom@6. Like, I want to redirect users to other pages If they logged in. But when I use Navigate component It threw error saying that :

"[Navigate] is not a  component. All component children of Routes must be a Route or React.Fragment"

Though I have wrapped it in the fragment but the result still the same. Please help me, this is my code:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import ProductList from './pages/ProductList';
import Product from './pages/Product';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Cart from './pages/Cart';
import ErrorPage from './pages/ErrorPage';

function App() {
  const user = true;
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/products/:category" element={<ProductList/>} />
        <Route path="/product/:id" element={<Product/>} />
        <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart/>} />
        <Route path="/dang-ky" element={<Register/>} />
        <Route path="/dang-nhap" element={<Login/>} >
          {user ? <><Navigate to="/" replace/></> : <Login/>}
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 9):

Redirecting users if logged in, necessarily does not need a navigation, you could simply just specify the element you want to reach eg:

```
<Route exact path="/"   element={user ? <Home/> : <Login />}/>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use Navigate component from 'react-router-dom' library and use it to redirect inside the element attribute of the '/login' route.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

<Route path="login" element={user ? <Navigate to="/"/> : <Login />} />    {/* If user is logged in, then redirect to home page, else go to login page */}
```

Comment: nice and easy, thanks! -- love the Navigate "redirect"

Comment: Nice and stright forward, i used it and it worked just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

This is also a possible solution, drawback is that you cant redirect properly. You just have to make sure that you have the fallbackroutes set up right.

```
{isSignedIn && <Route path="" element={} />}
```

I would recommend using an AuthRout to wrap your Routes.

```js
function AuthRoute ({children}) {
  if(!user.isSignedIn){
    //Not signed in
    return <Navigate to="/signIn" />
  }
  //Signed in
  return children
}

//Route itself
<Route path="/abc" element={<AuthRoute><YourComponent /></AuthRoute>} />
```

That way the user gets redirected if he is not signed in

Comment: hmm doesn't it seem a bit complicated?? Because at v5 version I just use the Redirect tag, not using a function like that haha

Comment: its not really complicated and i havent really found another solution for v6.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the that problem, but you can use `useNavigate` from `react-router-dom` v6

as below

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export const MyComponent = ({user}) => {
   const navigate = useNavigate();

   useEffect(() => {
       if(user){
          navigate('/dashboard')
        }else{
          navigate('/login')
        }
     ......

    },[])
  .....
}
```

and use that codes on your route logic, it makes your route more clean

```
<Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/products/:category" element={<ProductList/>} />
        <Route path="/product/:id" element={<Product/>} />
        <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart/>} />
        <Route path="/dang-ky" element={<Register/>} />
        <Route path="/dang-nhap" element={<MyComponent user = {user} />}/>
        <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```

Comment: hmm actually I just wanted to check the logic If it works by using ternary operator (like the codes above) Do you have any other ideas then? Thanks

Comment: And i assume that you want that on your route logics as you have done on your codes above? right?

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to check If i type url with the path like : localhost:3000/dang-ky (like above) with const user = true, It will direct user right away to homepage because of the const user is true :D

Comment: i've edited my post a little so that i have putted all that logic inside the wrapper component, i think its usable and makes your route codes clean,

Comment: thank you once again, but could you please take a look at this clip? At 10:20, I know he's using version 5, It's so easy to know  but I couldn't do the same as him haha https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y66RgYMAgSo&t=641s

Comment: Yes yes i've seeen it. i think to achieve that you should use logic as @whygee have done below. Its like he've done what you're trying to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240164/discussion-between-dennis-nguyen-and-ndotie).